# How to use Objectify of google app engine in servlet locally?

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, servlets, objectify

I am a beginner in using google app engine.
How can I use Objectify in this program for storing, locally? And also I want to edit and delete the data in the List.
I can't able to learn about "use of objectify locally in servlet and json", because of lack of websites on this topics.
Please someone help me with code.
Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

This is my servlet program.

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    List<Database> studentData = new LinkedList<>();
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String json = "";
    if (br != null) {
        json = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(json);
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Database studentDetails = mapper.readValue(json, Database.class);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    studentData.add(studentDetails);
    mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), studentData);
}
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
}
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration form</title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            clear: left;
            width: 85px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        input {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        table,th,td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myFunction.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <center>
            <h2><strong>Registration Form</strong></h2>
            <label>First name:</label><input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Firstname"><br><br>
            <label>Last name:</label><input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Lastname"><br><br>
            <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" id="fullname" placeholder="Enter your full name"><br><br>
            <label>Email ID:</label><input id="email" name="email" type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your email ID"><br><br>
            <label>Address:</label><input id="address" name="address" type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Address"><br><br>
            <label>Contact:</label><input id="contact" name="contact" type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your contact"><br><br>
            <label><input type="button" id="bttHello" onclick="register();" value="Register"></label><br><br>
            <span id="result1"></span>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 id="head">
            <center>
                <strong><em>Registered Student data</em></strong>
            </center>
        </h3>
        <center>
            <table id="added-data" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th id="firstName">First name</th>
                    <th id="Lastname">Last name</th>
                    <th id="FullName">Full name</th>
                    <th id="EmailID">Email ID</th>
                    <th id="Address">Address</th>
                    <th id="Contact">Contact</th>
                    <th id="Edit">Edit</th>
                    <th id="Delete"> Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

myFunction.js

```
function register() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bttHello").click(function () {
            var studentData = {};
            studentData.fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            studentData.first_name = $('#first_name').val();
            studentData.last_name = $('#last_name').val();
            studentData.email = $('#email').val();
            studentData.address = $('#address').val();
            studentData.contact = $('#contact').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Servlet',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(studentData),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                MimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("tr:has(td)").remove();
                    $.each(result, function (index, studentData) {
                        $("#added-data").append($('<tr/>')
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.first_name))
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.last_name))
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.fullname))
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.email))
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.address))
                            .append($('<td/>').html(studentData.contact))
                            .append($('<td/>').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn -default btn - sm'>" + "<span class= 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' >" + "</span>" + "Edit" + "</button >"))
                            .append($('<td/>').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'>" + "</span>" + " Remove" + "</button>"))
                        );
                    });
                },
                error: function (data, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + data + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```